# Python subprocess() runtime error: Exec format error with PosixPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I'm running into an issue with Python's subprocess module. Namely, calling another Python script using the subprocess.run() method. The problem seems to be in the Popen constructor. The error I'm getting is this: "OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: PosixPath." The interpreter seems to either not recognize the file path, or the arguments I provided are incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated. I did some digging around but I can't pinpoint the issue or how to resolve it!

Full code of CallingFile.py (error is on the `subprocess.run()` line):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

def input_window(process_select):
    input_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    input_window.title("Input")
    input_window.geometry("300x300")
    input_window.geometry(f"+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
        
    input_label = tk.Label(input_window,text = "Enter name")
    input_label.pack(pady = 10)
        
    input_var = tk.StringVar()
    input_entry = tk.Entry(input_window,textvariable = input_var)
    input_entry.pack(pady = 10)

    def execute_code(process_select):
        input_name = input_var.get()
        input_window.destroy()
        if process_select == 1:
            file_path = Path(__file__).with_name("MyFile.py")
            subprocess.run(file_path,text = True,input = input_name)
            
            confirm_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
            confirm_window.title("Confirmation")
            confirm_window.geometry(f"+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")
            
            message_label = tk.Label(confirm_window,text = "Process started successfully.")
            message_label.pack(pady = 10)

    start_button = ttk.Button(input_window,text = "Start",command = execute_code(process_select))
    start_button.pack()

def update_button_state():
    selected_option = dropdown_var.get()
    if selected_option == "Option1":
        select_button.state(["!disabled"])
        stop_button.state(["!disabled"])
    else:
        select_button.state(["disabled"])
        stop_button.state(["disabled"])
    root.after(100,update_button_state)  # Call the function again after 100 milliseconds

def execute_selection():
    selected_option = dropdown_var.get()
    # if selected_option == "":
    #     return
    if selected_option == "Option1":
        input_window(1)
    elif selected_option == "Option2":
        result = "Option 2 code executed"
    elif selected_option == "Option3":
        result = "Option 3 code executed"

    result_label = tk.Label(result_window,text = result)
    result_label.pack(padx = 20,pady = 10)

    ok_button = tk.Button(result_window,text = "OK",command = result_window.destroy)
    ok_button.pack(pady = 10)

def cancel_execution():
    messagebox.showinfo("Stop","Program stopped\nResults saved to:")# add filepath

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Program")

# Calculate screen width and height
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# Calculate center coordinates
x = (screen_width - root.winfo_reqwidth()) / 2
y = (screen_height - root.winfo_reqheight()) / 2

# Center and resize the main window
root.geometry("500x200")
root.geometry(f"+{int(x)}+{int(y)}")

# Create a label
message_label = tk.Label(root,text = "Welcome!\nPlease select an option:")
message_label.pack(pady = 10)

# Create a dropdown menu with blank default option
options = ["", "Option1", "Option2", "Option3"]
dropdown_var = tk.StringVar(root)
dropdown_var.set(options[0])
dropdown_var.trace("w",update_button_state)  # Call the update function when dropdown value changes
dropdown_menu = ttk.Combobox(root,textvariable = dropdown_var,values = options)
dropdown_menu.pack(pady = 10)

# Create start button
select_button = ttk.Button(root,text = "Run",command = execute_selection)
select_button.pack()

# Create stop button
stop_button = ttk.Button(root,text = "Stop",command = cancel_execution)
stop_button.pack()

# Start the button state update loop
update_button_state()

# Start the GUI event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the traceback with the relevant info:

```
File "/home/username/Desktop/.../CallingFile.py", line 28, in execute_code
    subprocess.run(file_path,text = True,input = trial_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 503, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: PosixPath('/home/username/Desktop/.../MyFile.py')
```

I've tried different workarounds like switching the order of my arguments or using a list (sequentializing), and calling the file using Python's Path. For the first two workaround, I just get a different error message. The last workaround led me to this error.

-----------------------------------------------------**UPDATE**-----------------------------------------------------------------

I incorporated Kim's suggestions and added the shbang to MyFile.py. I already had -x permissions on all Python files in this directory. After making the changes I got a new error message (bad window path name). However, I created three windows for this program. The first one is the main window. The second one shows up after I click "Run", and the third one appears after I click "Start." The second one went away, but the third one showed up . The code didn't fully execute because MyFile was supposed to get user input, and I never saw the prompt. Here is the full traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: update_button_state() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/username/Desktop/.../CallingFile.py", line 56, in execute_selection
    input_window(1)
  File "/home/username/Desktop/.../CallingFile.py", line 38, in input_window
    start_button = ttk.Button(input_window,text = "Start",command = execute_code(process_select))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/ttk.py", line 607, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::button", kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/ttk.py", line 552, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2601, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!toplevel"
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with MyFile.py, and not with your included code.

What are the permissions on MyFile.py? Is it executable? You can fix the permissions with:

```
chmod +x MyFile.py
```

Does MyFile.py start with `#!/usr/bin/env python` or a similar `#!` `python` construct?

Can you run MyFile.py from the shell?

```
./MyFile.py
```

Looking at your update there appear to be 3 separate errors. I'll comment on the one which is not Tkinter specific (as I haven't used Tkinter):

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

This looks like a script starting with `#!/usr/bin/env python` is being called, but python is not in a directory in the PATH environment variable. You could either check what PATH is being set when the script is being called, or you could change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/python` (or wherever your python interpreter is located) to directly call python without relying on the PATH being set.

If you find an answer useful, even if it doesn't completely answer the question, please vote it up as this gives credit to the person who responded.

Comment: Hi Kim , thank you so much for your response. I will try your suggestions and let you know if that is indeed the problem!